# Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) using some PCL functions

Tags: android, fatal-error, eigen, point-cloud-library, memory-alignment

I'm currently developping an application for the google tango tablet, so I have build pcl for ARM using the superbuild script
(from https://github.com/Sabotaz/pcl-superbuild-with-release/releases).

I experience a strange crash : one of the pcl function, pcl::ProjectInliers, makes a «Fatal signal 
7 (SIGBUS)» error.

I didn't completly understand this error, the doc says that «it could happend when dereferencing a misaligned pointer, such as referring to a four-word integer at an address not divisible by four.», so I don't understand, looking to my code, how it can happens.

Beside, all my variables seems to be well aligned (I checked that using https://stackoverflow.com/a/1898156/5533171).

Backtraces seems to involves Eigen data structure misalignment, so I think the issue is not in my code, but on the 3rd party libraries.

Here is the relevant part of my code (based on http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/planar_segmentation.php):

```
template<typename T> void SegmentationEngine<T>::ransac_loop(typename pcl::PointCloud<T>::Ptr cloud_blob, std::vector<Datatype::RansacPlane<T>>& planes) {

    LOGD("size : %d", cloud_blob->points.size ());
    typename pcl::PointCloud<T>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<T>);
    copyPointCloud(*cloud_blob, *cloud);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < FILTER_SEGMENTATION_MAX_PLANES_NUMBER) {

        typename pcl::PointCloud<T>::Ptr points (new pcl::PointCloud<T>);
        pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers (new pcl::PointIndices ());
        pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients ());

        LOGD("remaining : %d", cloud->points.size ());
        LOGD("Filters::sac_segmentation");
        if (!Filters::sac_segmentation<T>(cloud,inliers, coefficients)) break; // plus de plans

        LOGD("found plane with %d pts", inliers->indices.size());
        // it crash here :
        Filters::project_inliers<T>(cloud, inliers, coefficients, points, false); // don't copy all (extract)

        planes.push_back( Datatype::RansacPlane<T>{ coefficients, points } );

        typename pcl::PointCloud<T>::Ptr remaining (new pcl::PointCloud<T>);

        Filters::extract_indices<T>(cloud, inliers, remaining, true); // remaining
        cloud.swap(remaining);
        i++;
    }
    LOGD("n planes : %d", planes.size());
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename T> bool sac_segmentation(typename pcl::PointCloud<T>::Ptr input_cloud, pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers, pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients) {

    // Create the segmentation object
    pcl::SACSegmentation<T> seg;
    // Optional
    seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (FILTER_SAC_SEGMENTATION_OPTIMIZE_COEFFICIENTS);
    // Mandatory
    seg.setModelType (FILTER_SAC_SEGMENTATION_MODEL_TYPE);
    seg.setMethodType (FILTER_SAC_SEGMENTATION_METHOD_TYPE);
    seg.setDistanceThreshold (FILTER_SAC_SEGMENTATION_DISTANCE_THRESOLD);
    seg.setMaxIterations (FILTER_SAC_SEGMENTATION_MAX_ITERATIONS);

    seg.setInputCloud (input_cloud);
    seg.segment (*inliers, *coefficients);

    if (inliers->indices.size () == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename T> void project_inliers(typename pcl::PointCloud<T>::Ptr input_cloud, pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers, pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients, typename pcl::PointCloud<T>::Ptr output_cloud, bool copyall) {
    // Project the model inliers
    typename pcl::ProjectInliers<T> proj;
    proj.setModelType (FILTER_PROJECT_INLIERS_MODEL_TYPE);
    if (inliers != NULL)
        proj.setIndices (inliers);
    proj.setInputCloud (input_cloud);
    proj.setModelCoefficients (coefficients);
    proj.setCopyAllData (copyall);
    // it crash here :
    proj.filter (*output_cloud);
}
```

Here are the corresponding log :

```
D/fr.limsi.registration: size : 36 
D/fr.limsi.registration: remaining : 36 
D/fr.limsi.registration: Filters::sac_segmentation 
D/fr.limsi.registration: found plane with 36 pts 
A/libc: Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x4be4fa38 (code=1), thread 1052 (si.registration)
```

here is the backtrace :

```
backtrace: 
#00 pc 0055d55e /data/app-lib/fr.limsi.registration-1/libintegration.so 
(std::vector<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal, Eigen::aligned_allocator_indirection<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal> 
>::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal*, 
std::vector<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal, Eigen::aligned_allocator_indirection<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal> > 
>, unsigned int, pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal const&)+621) 
#01 pc 0064d995 /data/app-lib/fr.limsi.registration-1/libintegration.so 
(std::vector<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal, Eigen::aligned_allocator<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal> 
>::resize(unsigned int)+116) 
#02 pc 008cc23b /data/app-lib/fr.limsi.registration-1/libintegration.so 
(pcl::SampleConsensusModelPlane<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>::projectPoints(std::vector<int, 
std::allocator<int> > const&, Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&, 
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>&, bool)+514) 
#03 pc 0066b457 /data/app-lib/fr.limsi.registration-1/libintegration.so 
(pcl::ProjectInliers<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>::applyFilter(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>&)+ 
82)
```

If someone have an idea of what could happend, let me know :)

Thank you,

Sablier

Comment: Could you try to `#include <Eigen/StdVector>` before including any PCL library? Perhaps you are hitting an issue that `std::vector<...>::resize` passes an argument by value (prior to C++11). Alternatively, if possible compile in C++11 mode.

Comment: I already  use the C++11 mode :/... I wonder if the problem can be that pcl was built with android_ndk_r8, and I build the rest of my code with the latest ndk...